# Supervisord set user:group for program

Tags: supervisord

I am running Nginx, Gunicorn with Supervisord. After Supervisord starts it creates `gunicorn.sock` file with user and group `my_user:my_user`. I need Nginx to be able to connect to the socket file `gunicorn.sock` is there any proper method to set socket file user and group to `my_user:nginx`?

I have tried to set this settings bellow to `[myprogram:program]` but it does not work:

```
socket_owner=my_user:nginx
chown=my_user:nginx
```

My supervisord.conf program:

```
[myprogram:program]
command = /var/www/project/virtual_env/bin/gunicorn -k gevent --worker-connections 1001 --bind=unix:gunicorn.sock -m 007 wsgi:application
directory = /var/www/project/
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you could run Gunicorn as the same user that Nginx runs as? Then the created socket will have the necessary ownership. Of course this may require you to adjust the permissions of your application directory.

Supervisor has a `user` directive that can be used for this. For example, if Nginx runs as the `www-data` user, you could use this Supervisor configuration.

```
[myprogram:program]
command = /var/www/project/virtual_env/bin/gunicorn -k gevent --worker-connections 1001 --bind=unix:gunicorn.sock -m 007 wsgi:application
directory = /var/www/project/
user = www-data
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected
```

This results in the following ownership and permissions (the resulting group depends on the configuration of the user account).

```
# ls -lh gunicorn.sock
srwxrwx--- 1 www-data www-data 0 Dec 24 22:43 gunicorn.sock
```

Something similar to this works for me with Nginx, Gunicorn, and Django on Debian Stretch.

Answer (score 4):

It's already 2021 but I believe this answer may help someone. Nginx uses the user "www-data". The solution to this is to add this user to your user's group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G my_user www-data
```

Remember to change "my_user" with the group name for your current user.

Restart the supervisor service for your app.

Comment: It works, but it also gives extra privileges to www-data, which you may want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get around this, while keeping the nginx and gunicorn users separate, and thus without giving away too many permissions, is to use systemd instead of supervisor for gunicorn.

In the current docs https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/20.1.0/deploy.html#systemd it gives this setup+comment for the socket unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock
# Our service won't need permissions for the socket, since it
# inherits the file descriptor by socket activation
# only the nginx daemon will need access to the socket
SocketUser=www-data
# Optionally restrict the socket permissions even more.
# SocketMode=600

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```